# What is a company's benefit of training employees in cybersecurity?

Tags: professional-education, user-education

I'm a federally employed senior executive assistant with a user-knowledge in computer programs and software. I'm trying to change my career and am looking for my employer to pay for my training. I'm interested in cybersecurity; it appears to be challenging and fascinating too. My employer is requiring me to submit a request that includes "Why I'm interested and what benefit is it to them".

I thought I compiled the right language, but apparently it wasn't good enough. So, I'm reaching out to you for some support. I can't simply tell them that I'm bored, and my current position doesn't have any mobility. What should I do?

Comment: IMHO being Federally employed greatly increases the need for security training. All you need is one weak link in the chain to get a starting point to base a bigger attack from, or map out what you need to launch one... which, when you consider the targets are in the government, makes the reward that much more juicy.

Answer (score 4):

An interesting question.

In mind there's probably at least a few answers.

**Training the Average Employee**

These days corporations are evolving their average employee training to include cybersecurity with an eye to "if everyone operates securely, we'll be at less risk of loosing business data, reputation, or other key facets of the business to a cybersecurity attack" - this comes down to the "you're only as strong as your weakest link" argument.

However, I don't see the training of this sort being the kind of thing that's really going to increase your job skills - so I'd say this probably isn't the position or type of course you are going for.

**Training the Management**

Management will always be in the business of weighing tradeoffs between available resources and business goals.  These days "less vulnerable to cybersecurity attack" is a very viable business goal in almost every business of any scale.  Courses that teach management the factors involved in this area and some common techniques for trading of risk to assets vs. cost of security controls is certainly worth while.  There's courses and certifications out there for this, but with an uneducated corporation, you'll have to figure out a way to explain what the risks are for this business and connect it to why the training will help.

Note - this is a management case - if you are not yet management, then making this case will probably be of limited use.

**Training Technical Knowledge Workers - IT, Engineering, etc.**

My definition here (to be completely vague) is anyone with a job that centers around building "computer stuff" for the company - networking, system administration, software development, solution development, desktop support or any other area - whether this is focused on keeping the tools of the business running or developing product on which the business depends.

The trick to making a case here is that this is just another facet to "using the tools and techniques correctly" - don't make a huge leap from your area of current expertise to a whole new topic.  For example, if you are a system administrator, you may not easily be able to jump to a course in the low level mathematics behind cryptography - if your boss is clued in, he'll have real trouble seeing how that crypto course is going to help you.  But if you are a LINUX admin, taking a course on Securing LINUX is just as relevant to your job as taking Advanced LINUX configuration - it's teaching you how to use a tool correctly and with the best practices that make it easier to maintain.

I'd take it from that angle - "I am a X job, and the company has invested a great deal in A, B, C tools.  The need to securely manage and use these tools has been a growing topic within in the industry.  I'm looking to take a course on security that is relevant to these tools so I can be better and more efficient at making the security features of these tools work correctly for our company".

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion , most companies only take security seriously when 1. It's part of their key performance indicators or 2. When they get hacked.

And since you are working for the government then security should be part of their KPI? So benefits to them would be to be aware about the real world security vulnerabilities and take necessary precautions to prevent / avoid attacks to prevent loss of confidential information.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking to get training as a the information security field.  That means you have to sell them on the need for an information security specialist.  And that means knowing what a security specialist does.

The role of a CISSP includes ten domains ([taken from the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certified_Information_Systems_Security_Professional#Certification_subject_matter)):

```
Access control
Telecommunications and network security
Information security governance and risk management
Software development security
Cryptography
Security architecture and design
Operations security
Business continuity and disaster recovery planning
Legal, regulations, investigations and compliance
Physical (environmental) security
```

You should try mapping those areas of knowledge to your department.  Do they need someone to handle operational security?  Do they follow a secure software development lifecycle?  Do they have someone doing risk management that needs help?

Only you know your own area.  Figure out your current weaknesses, and highlight where you could help them protect their systems if you had the appropriate training.  In the meantime, do whatever reading you can on the topic.  Demonstrate a willingness to learn, and an aptitude for the topic, and you may gain a bit of respect with them.